# CL GL Interop: CL context creation parameters

Tags: opengl, opencl, lwjgl, glfw

I've been trying to create an OpenCL context bound to an OpenGL context. I've failed to find the appropriate values for the `properties` parameter needed for the `KHRGLSharing.clGetGLContextInfoKHR` method to query the devices available. The OpenGL context is created using GLFW and the window I want to work with is the current context (set with `glfwMakeContextCurrent`)

The following code snipped shows what I've come up with so far:

```
public static List<Long> queryDevicesForPlatform(long platform) {
        stack.push(); // MemoryStack defined elsewhere
        //Create properties
        //Problematic piece of code
        long[] properties =  switch (Platform.get()) {
            //These parameters let the JVM crash when clGetGLContextInfoKHR is called
            case LINUX -> new long[]{
                    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform,
                    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, GLX14.glXGetCurrentContext(),
                    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, GLX14.glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
                    0
            };
            //Not yet tested
            case MACOSX -> new long[]{
                    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform,
                    CL_CGL_SHAREGROUP_KHR, CGL.CGLGetShareGroup(CGL.CGLGetCurrentContext()),
                    0
            };
            //This one works
            case WINDOWS -> new long[]{
                    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform,
                    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, glfwGetCurrentContext(),
                    CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, wglGetCurrentDC(),
                    0
            };
        };

        //Copy properties to a buffer
        ByteBuffer byteProp = stack.malloc(properties.length * Long.BYTES);
        byteProp.asLongBuffer().put(properties);
        ByteBuffer bytes = stack.malloc(Long.BYTES);

        //JVM crashes here
        int error = KHRGLSharing.clGetGLContextInfoKHR(PointerBuffer.create(byteProp),
                CL_DEVICES_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (ByteBuffer) null, PointerBuffer.create(bytes));
        assert error == CL22.CL_SUCCESS: error;

        ByteBuffer value = stack.malloc((int) bytes.asLongBuffer().get(0));
        error = KHRGLSharing.clGetGLContextInfoKHR(PointerBuffer.create(byteProp), CL_DEVICES_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, value, null);
        assert error == CL22.CL_SUCCESS: error;
        LongBuffer devices = value.asLongBuffer();

        ArrayList<Long> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        while(devices.hasRemaining()) {
            ret.add(devices.get());
        }

        stack.pop();
        return ret;
    }
```

Linux: I do not know what values to pass for `CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM`, `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR` and `CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR`. The current crash the JVM with a `SIGSEGV`.

Windows: The code works, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it.

Apple: I have no machine to test this on, but I would appreciate it if I'd know the right parameters there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel's Linux drivers do not support CL-GL interop (it lacks the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension).
The code snippet should work on Linux if the driver supports CL-GL interop